Error when importing flask_cors in Flask application
I'm developing a Flask application in Python where I need to use the flask_cors package to handle Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policy in AJAX requests. However, when trying to import flask_cors, I'm getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_cors'.
Here's a snippet of my code:
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from noticias import noticias_bp
from user import *

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
# Define a secret key for the Flask application.
app.secret_key = '2002'
# Register the user_bp blueprint in the Flask application, assigning it the URL prefix '/user'.
app.register_blueprint(user_bp)
app.register_blueprint(noticias_bp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


terminal:
PS C:\Users\ferre\Projects\Portal-de-Noticias\backend> & c:/Users/ferre/Projects/Portal-de-Noticias/backend/.venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/ferre/Projects/Portal-de-Noticias/backend/user_registration/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ferre\Projects\Portal-de-Noticias\backend\user_registration\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_cors import CORS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_cors'
PS C:\Users\ferre\Projects\Portal-de-Noticias\backend> 

I've already installed the flask_cors package using the command pip install flask-cors, and I've verified that the package is listed when I run pip list. However, I continue to receive the import error.
image
Does anyone have any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

are you active env or have many version python?.
